# Names of winds in Spain

Tags: etimología, vocabulario, españa, tiempo-meteorológico

Right now at my place we're getting 45 knot winds, coming from the Southwest.
I know that this wind is called [***Lebeche***](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebeche) in Spain, but why is it called like that?

And, since it would be silly to make a different question for each different wind...
**What are the names of the different winds in Spain? And what is the origin of each name?**

Just to be clear, I'm asking about names of winds found in Spain in particular, not about the Spanish name of every single wind in the world ;)

---

NOTA: Por descontado, se aceptan respuestas en español (nombres de los vientos y etimología).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you have the most common (and also some uncommon) winds in Spain, according to the direction they blow from, taken from the [Spanish Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosa_de_los_vientos#Los_nombres_de_los_vientos_del_Mediterr%C3%A1neo), the [*Eolonimia* page](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eolionimia) and [other](https://noticias.eltiempo.es/10-vientos-espana/) sources (entries restricted to those appearing in the [DLE](https://dle.rae.es)):

**North**

- [Tramontana](https://dle.rae.es/?id=aGVm8G6). From *[transmontano](https://dle.rae.es/?id=aLjPyVs)*, Latin *transmontānus*, "coming from the other side of the mountains".
- [Terral](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ZbKTODN). From *tierra*, literallly "coming from the earth".
- [Bóreas](https://dle.rae.es/?id=5uHTUcX). From Latin *[bŏrĕas](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=boreas&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)* "the north wind", from Greek βορέας *boréas*.
- [Etesio](https://dle.rae.es/?id=H3uqSX8). From Latin *[ĕtēsius](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DE%3Aentry%20group%3D26%3Aentry%3Detesius)*, from Greek ἐτήσιος *etḗsios* "yearly".
- [Septentrión](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Xd5a8r2). From Latin *[septentrio, -ōnis](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=septentriones&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)*, "the north wind", from *septem* "seven" and *trio, -ōnis*, from [Trĭōnes](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Triones&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), the constellation of the Wain, i. e. *Ursa Major* and *Ursa Minor* (which were compared to a wagon with oxen yoked to it).
- [Matacabras](https://dle.rae.es/?id=OZso86K). Literally "goat killer". Also [descuernacabras](https://dle.rae.es/?id=CmUV6UN), literally "able to remove the horns of the goats".

**North-East**

- [Gregal](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JWLunb3). From Latin *Graecālis* "from Greece". Also known as *gregario* or *greco*.
- [Cecias](https://dle.rae.es/?id=85TXHTe). From Latin *[caecĭas](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=caecias&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)* "the north-east wind", from Greek καικίας *kaikías*.

**East**

- [Levante](https://dle.rae.es/?id=NCHYFRd). From the cardinal point of the same name, and this from *levar* and *-nte*.
- [Solano](https://dle.rae.es/?id=YFjJ9oH) or [subsolano](https://dle.rae.es/?id=YZoufrW). From Latin *[Sōlānus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DS%3Aentry%20group%3D50%3Aentry%3DSolanus)*, "east wind". Also known colloquially as [rabiazorras](https://dle.rae.es/?id=UyeQ9yl).

**South-East**

- [Siroco](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Y1KD2YG) or [jaloque](https://dle.rae.es/?id=MJufSMX). Maybe from Catalan *[e]xaloc*, from Hispanic Arabic *šaláwq* "sea wind", from Latin *[sălum](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=salum&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)* "the open sea" or even "a sea of thought, agitation, trouble, etc.".
- [Bochorno](https://dle.rae.es/?id=5jUiVu3). From Latin *[Vulturnus ventus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DV%3Aentry%20group%3D29%3Aentry%3DVulturnus%20ventus)*, "a southeastby-one-third-south wind", from *[Vultur](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DV%3Aentry%20group%3D29%3Aentry%3DVultur2)*, a mountain in Apulia.

**South**

- [Austro](https://dle.rae.es/?id=4QTMznk) or [ostro](https://dle.rae.es/?id=RJs1qRX). From Latin *[auster, -tri](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DA%3Aentry%20group%3D93%3Aentry%3Dauster1)*, "the south wind".
- [Castellano](https://dle.rae.es/?id=7qluXx1). Used colloquially in the Álava region, as it comes from the Castilla region.

**South-West**

- [Lebeche](https://dle.rae.es/?id=N2D2nL0). From Hispanic Arabic *labáč*, from Latin *[Lĭbycus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DL%3Aentry%20group%3D22%3Aentry%3DLibya)* "of Libya", as it blows from that direction.
- [Garbino](https://dle.rae.es/?id=It2FZfT). From Hispanic Arabic *ḡarbí*, from Classic Arabic *ḡarbī* "western".
- [Ábrego](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0AVeMd0). From Latin *[Afrĭcus ventus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DA%3Aentry%20group%3D31%3Aentry%3DAfrica)* "African wind".

**West**

- [Poniente](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Tdz6mVq). From the cardinal point of the same name, from Latin *ponens, -entis*. Also poeticallly known as [favonio](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Hgqm1T5), from Latin *[Făvōnĭus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=favonius&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)*; or [céfiro](https://dle.rae.es/?id=86qQvqg), from Latin *[Zĕphyrus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Zephyrus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)*.
- [Vendaval](https://dle.rae.es/?id=bWLYrjB). From French *vent d'aval* "wind from down under".
- [Euro](https://dle.rae.es/?id=H6HMVNH). From Latin *[eurus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=eurus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)*, "the east wind", from Greek εὖρος *eûros*.

**North-West**

- [Mistral](https://dle.rae.es/?id=PPtX033). From Occitan *mistral* "north-west wind". Also *[maestral](https://dle.rae.es/?id=NrkaYyL)*, from Latin *[magistrālis](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=magistralis&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)*.
- [Galerna](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Iju6CxW). From French *galerne* "north-west wind". From Breton *gwalarn*, from root *gal*, "wind".
- [Cierzo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=9BgGZ9c). From Latin *cercius*, see *[circius](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Circius&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)*, "a west-northwest wind".
- [Gallego](https://dle.rae.es/?id=IlFjdhI). From Latin *[Gallaecus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DG%3Aentry%20group%3D2%3Aentry%3DGallaeci)*, wind coming from the Galician region.
- [Cauro](https://dle.rae.es/?id=80Hcg1m) or [coro](https://dle.rae.es/?id=AupYhkK). From Latin *[Caurus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=caurus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)*, "the north-west wind".

Some other winds, not typically from Spain but known enough here:

- [Alisios](https://dle.rae.es/?id=1t9MXIQ). Of unknown origin.
- [Simún](https://dle.rae.es/?id=XwHfas9). From French *simoun*, from dialectal Arabic *smūm*, from Classic Arabic *samūm* "pestilent wind".

Comment: Quite interesting, but the explanation doesn't explain it completely,  Did Lybia encompass Morocco at some time? Or has the expression previously been used in the Eastern Mediterrenean? (In Corsica and other parts of Italy, they have the same wind - spelt *Libeccio*.)

Comment: [Nordés](https://gl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nord%C3%A9s_(vento)), from Galicia in the North-West

Comment: @Chirlo "nordés" es una palabra gallega, por eso no está incluida en la lista, pero gracias por tu aportación.

Comment: @charlie, the question reads "What are the names of the different winds in Spain?" . Galicia is in Spain, so it applies

Comment: @Chirlo yes, Galicia is in Spain, but this is a site about the Spanish language, not the Galician language. For the same reason I have included "jaloque" and not "xaloc", the name in Catalan.

Comment: @FrankfromFrankfurt that may be an interesting question for the [History.SE] site.